# Codeigniter $this->db->where() not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, where-clause

```
$this->db->from('posts');
$this->db->where('id',$this->uri->segment(3));
$data['query'] = $this->db->get();
```

I am trying to get one post using a where statement. I don't get any errors when I run this code. But in my view when I try to get `$query->result()->body` PHP gives me an error `Trying to get property of non-object.` So I ran `print_r($query)` and this is what it gave me:

```
(
    [conn_id] => Resource id #27
    [result_id] => Resource id #32
    [result_array] => Array
        (
        )

    [result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [custom_result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [current_row] => 0
    [num_rows] => 0
    [row_data] => 
)
```

I have no idea why it won't get my specific post from the database. I know my database is in working condition. I use it elsewhere in my site. I also use `$this->db->where()` elsewhere on my site and it works perfect. I've also tried plugging in id's of posts instead of `$this->uri->segment(3)` and I get the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result()` should be used when you are selecting more than 1 row from db, use `row()` instead.

In controller use

```
$data['query'] = $this->db->get()->row();
```

And then in view

```
$query->body
```

I strongly reccomend you to use `$data['post']` and `$post->body` instead of `$query->body`. When you will have more queries on one page, your view will get messy.